# How can I set default active dashlets for all users globally?

Tags: dashboard, ux, default-settings

Can I create a default dashboard setup (active dashlets and arrangement) for all users?

This would greatly improve the usability of the Dashboard, since the dashlets relevant to the use-case of the organization could be configured by an admin and users would see relevant data on their home screen instead of "CiviCRM News" or just this:

> Welcome to your Home Dashboard
>   Your dashboard provides a one-screen view of the data that's most
>   important to you. Graphical or tabular data is pulled from the reports
>   you select, and is displayed in 'dashlets' (sections of the
>   dashboard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DefaultDashlets](https://github.com/davidjosephhayes/CiviCRM-Default-Dashlets) CiviCRM extension creates a settings page that allows administrators to define the active dashlets for new users based on group membership.

Keep in mind it was born some hours ago as part of a CiviCRM developer training exercise. You rock [David Hayes](https://github.com/davidjosephhayes)!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use SQL!  There is an API and a hook for this, assuming you're on Civi 4.4 or higher.

Check out the [DashboardContact API](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/API+changes#APIchanges-4.4.?:DashboardContactAPI--Enabledeveloperstoassigndashletstothedashboardforparticularusers), especially if you're working with contacts that have already been created.

If you're mostly concerned about new users, I'd recommend exploring [hook_civicrm_dashboard_defaults](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_dashboard_defaults).

Comment: Thank you @Jon G, that's better than a SQL query. I am going to look into creating an extension with the API functions you mention.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a front-end way to set a default, but you can use a SQL query to copy the dashboard setup from your "template" contact to new users as you create them. Below is an example:

```
insert into civicrm_dashboard_contact (
    dashboard_id,
    contact_id,
    column_no,
    is_minimized,
    is_fullscreen,
    is_active,
    weight,
    content,
    created_date)
select
    dashboard_id,
    35, -- replace with new contact id
    column_no,
    is_minimized,
    is_fullscreen,
    is_active,
    weight,
    content,
    NOW()
from
    civicrm_dashboard_contact 
where 
    contact_id = 1 -- replace with contact id whose dashboard you want to copy
;
```

If you use a certain contact type/group/tag to define back office users, you can join to the appropriate table and do it all at once rather than one contact at a time.

Comment: Thanks @Nicholai, this is not at all what I wanted to hear, but I am very grateful that you shared this query!

Comment: I guess you could create an extension that do what Nicholai propose automatically when a new contact is created using hook_civicrm_post.

Comment: @samuelsov creating an extension is a great idea! Thanks.